# Connection refused even after installing openssh-server

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vnc, openssh

I have been spending the last 4 hours trying to get my VNC connection to work. Eventually, I realized it was because my Ubuntu remote host was unable to host SSH connections- **even though I had already installed openssh-server**.

I then tried some basic tests to verify that `sshd` was working on my machine, and found that `ssh localhost` gives a `Connection refused on port 22` error. Also, `sudo service ssh start` and `sudo start ssh` both give a `start: Unknown job: ssh` error. I tried purging and reinstalling `openssh-server`, but no luck. Why can't I receive clients?

**EDIT:** When I try to connect via the local machines (the VNC viewers) they give me a `Connection timed out` error.

**EDIT_2:** As requested, here is the output of `apt-cache policy openssh-server`:

```
openssh-server:
  Installed: 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-updates/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:6.6p1-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty/main armhf Packages
```

Comment: Do you have set up a firewall? maybe the server firewall (iptables?) is blocking the connection at port 22.

Comment: @RegisteredUser I just did an install of `ufw` (uncomplicated firewall) and it says the status is inactive, so I don't think I have one.

Comment: Have a look at `sudo iptables --list`

Comment: @RegisteredUser I have no idea what they mean, but [here is what I found](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ed8c007d7832aa33232e).

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy openssh-server`

Comment: @A.B. Finished editing.

Comment: There is no firewall blocking, so it must be something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do

```
sudo ufw enable
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install gufw
```

Then open your Dash and search for "Firewall". Open it and the rest should be self explaining.

Comment: I seem to have gotten [an error](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/435dc16358cea760e2a0) when running `sudo ufw enable`.

Comment: @JamesKo Well maybe purging and reinstalling will help.

Comment: Have you read this? "`sudo service ssh start` and `sudo start ssh` both give a start: Unknown job: ssh error"

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by manually starting `sshd`:

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/sshd
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/run/sshd
sudo /usr/sbin/sshd
```